# Multiple MongoDB connections to multiple mongo routers (mongos.exe)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have a system where there are multiple mongo shards (on large AWS instances), 3 mongo configs (on small AWS instances) and 3 mongo routers "mongos.exe" running (these are on the same instances as the app's i.e. 2 Tomcat's and 1 Java app).

So my question is, should each app (e.g. tomcat 1) talk to the mongos.exe on that box, and only that, or should it also have a connection to the mongos.exe's on the other 2 boxes (I'm thinking no single point of failure here).

In the mongo documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/ you can connect to multiple mongo's using the following: -

```
// or, to connect to a replica set, with auto-discovery of the primary, supply a seed list of members
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018),
    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27019)));
```

Is this the way to go? If so, my last question is, what does Spring configuration look?  My spring config on the app's looks like this: -

```
<mongo:mongo host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}">
    <mongo:options threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="${db.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier}"
                   connections-per-host="${db.connectionsPerHost}"
                   connect-timeout="${db.connectTimeout}"
                   max-wait-time="${db.maxWaitTime}"
                   auto-connect-retry="${db.autoConnectRetry}"
                   socket-timeout="${db.socketTimeout}"/>
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="${db.name}" mongo-ref="mongo" />
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/JEmDq1LAuPk/tvJpndLdLBoJ) with the correct answer.

```
<mongo:mongo id="replicaSetMongo" replica-set="127.0.0.1:27017,localhost:27018"/>
```

I tried, and also works with a single host, just like the "host" attribute.